# Button doesn't bind to function in viewmodel with caliburn micro

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn

I have the following xaml code in my view:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Klanten_beheer.Views.CustomerListView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Input.Toolkit">

    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Grid.Row="0">
        <Button x:Name="ToLastRecord" Content="&lt;&lt;" Background="LightSkyBlue"/>
```

And the following code in my viewmodel:

```
public class CustomerListViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
{
    #region Fields

    private IObservableCollection<Client> m_clients;

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    public int Position { get; private set; }

    public IObservableCollection<Client> Clients
    {
        get { return Clients; }
        set { Clients = value; }
    }

    public Client SelectedClient
    {
        get 
        {
            if ((Position < m_clients.Count) && (Position > -1))
            {
                return m_clients[Position];
            }
            else
            {
               return m_clients[0];
            }
        }
        set 
        {
            Position = m_clients.IndexOf(m_clients.Where(x => x.ClientNumber ==        value.ClientNumber).FirstOrDefault());
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    CustomerListViewModel(int position)
    {
        using (ClientDbEntities ctx = new ClientDbEntities())
        {
            var m_clients = (from client in ctx.Clients
                            orderby client.ClientNumber
                            select client).ToList();

            if (m_clients.Count != 0 && position < m_clients.Count)
            {
                Position = position;
            }
            else if (position >= m_clients.Count)
            {
                // Do nothing
            }
            else
            {
                Position = -1;
            }
        }
    }

        public CustomerListViewModel()
        {
            Position = 0;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Public functions

        public bool CanToLastRecord()
        {
            return true;
        }

        public void ToLastRecord()
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("ToLastRecord");
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

I would expect that the function `ToLastRecord` was trigger when the button is pushed.
For some reason the function is never triggert.

Comment: I saw I was missing a code fragment of my view:


        <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Grid.Row="0">
            <Button x:Name="ToLastRecord" Content="&lt;&lt;" Background="LightSkyBlue"/>

Comment: How do you expect the function to run if you never call it? [Start here to understand Commands in MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn237302.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for answering Tzah Mama but I thought that this was were caliburn micro was for the binding should go automaticaly on naming conventions.

See example caliburn.micro.hello

Comment: I've never heard of Caliburn before. I'm sorry if this is suppose to be it's normal behavior then :)

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been awhile - but forever who'll come up to this,
you should really take a look at [Caliburn.micro cheat-sheet](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Cheat%20Sheet)

The answer is right there at the top of the page - in order to attach an action to a default event (on buttons clicks do count) you need to use

```
<Button x:Name="ToLastRecord" Content="&lt;&lt;" Background="LightSkyBlue"  cal:Message.Attach="ToLastRecord"/>
```

Don't forget to add the following line to UserControl element:

```
xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
```

Comment: This is incorrect. The page shows that the default convention is to call the method directly without any additional attributes on the Button element. This actually works out of the box.